# parse error on objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>
#import <Foundation/NSAutoreleasePool.h>
#import <Foundation/NSEnumerator.h>
#import <stdio.h>

void print( NSArray *array ) {
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
id obj;

while ( obj = [enumerator nextObject] ) {
    printf( "%s\n", [[obj description] cString] );
}
}

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                @"Me", @"Myself", @"I", nil];
NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// enumerate over items
printf( "----static array\n" );
print( arr );

// add stuff
[mutable addObject: @"One"];
[mutable addObject: @"Two"];
[mutable addObjectsFromArray: arr];
[mutable addObject: @"Three"];

// print em
printf( "----mutable array\n" );
print( mutable );

// sort then print
printf( "----sorted mutable array\n" );
[mutable sortUsingSelector: @selector( caseInsensitiveCompare: )];
print( mutable );

// free memory
[arr release];
[mutable release];
[pool release];

return 0;
}
```

this program compiled with oscv0.1.4 in windows.
it gives an error as shown below

```
Error: Parse error on line 6:
...import <stdio.h>

void print( NSArray 
---------------------^
Expecting 'INTERFACE', 'IMPLEMENTATION', 'PROTOCOL', 'IMPORT', 'CLASS', 'DEFINE', 'EOF'
```

now i got one more error for the program shown below(it is another program)

```
#import "Forwarder.h"
#import "Recipient.h"

int main(void)
{
    Forwarder *forwarder = [Forwarder new];
    Recipient *recipient = [Recipient new];

[forwarder setRecipient:recipient]; //Set the recipient.
[forwarder hello];

[recipient release];
[forwarder release];

return 0;
}
```

error is

```
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...Recipient : Object
- (id)hello;
@end#i
----------------------^
Expecting '<', '{'
```

Comment: I've never heard of oscv (and I'm not seeing anything relevant on a quick Google search for that); have you tried another compiler like GCC?  Does oscv have an option to show you the preprocessed source file (equivalent of GCC's `-E` option)?

Comment: go through this link http://code.google.com/p/oscompiler/downloads/list

Comment: i compile and run another program with this compiler.It is ok.

Comment: please refer this link also http://www.qckapp.com/index.html?p=ObjC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the format of your program must like the code shown below
here main must contain Main class
compare this with the link
http://code.google.com/p/oscompiler/downloads/list

```
@interface Main : NSObject { }
@end

@implementation Main
+(void)main {
NSLog(@"Hello world!");
}
@end
```